# Why does Tensorflow/Keras say that my labels and shapes must have equal dimensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When ever I go to train my model using model.fit, I get a value error

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2662 and 64 for 'loss/output_1_loss/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [2662,1], [2662,64,64,128].`

I'm using a 64x64 3 channel image, however, I don't know where the 128 came from. Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Code attached:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
data = "*data\\*training\\*\\*"
filelist = glob.glob(str(data))
classes = ('classa','classb','classc','classd')
batchsize = 10
steps = (int(input("Enter Steps: "))/10)
def generator(file):
    f = tf.io.read_file(file)
    f = tf.image.decode_jpeg(f)
    f = tf.cast(f, tf.float32)
    f = tf.expand_dims(f,0)
    print(tf.shape(f))
    l = file.split('\\')
    l = l[2]
    l_label = classes.index(l)
    r1 = tf.constant(l_label)
    return f, r1
def todataset():
    array1 = []
    array2 = []
    for file in filelist:
        push_to_array1, push_to_array2 = generator(file)
        array1.append(push_to_array1)
        array2.append(push_to_array2)
    dataseta = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(array1)
    datasetb = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(array2)
    print(dataseta.element_spec)
    print(datasetb.element_spec)
    return(tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataseta,datasetb)))

dataset = todataset().shuffle(10000)
print(dataset.element_spec)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(128, (2,2), padding="same")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'], batch_size = batchsize)


model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch = steps)
model.save('MyModel.h5')
```

Comment: I believe the 128 is coming from the colors contained in each image.  So depending on how you loaded in your data and if you did so with or without colors, the 128 is most likely the possible values for your color at each pixel

Comment: are you passing the images in with full colors?

Comment: Yes, I am loading my images in with color.